# Formulation of $A_\infty$ structures in terms of coalgebras

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-algebra, a-infinity-algebras

There are two ways to define $A_\infty$ structures. The elementary one seems rather intuitive when I think of higher homotopies. I.e. an $A_\infty$ structure on a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector $A$ space is a sequence of maps $(m_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $m_n:A^{\otimes n} \to A$ is of degree $n-2$, satisfying the $A_\infty$-relations: $$\sum_{r+s+t=n-1}(-1)^{r+st}m_n\circ(id^{\otimes r}\otimes m_s\otimes id^{\otimes s})=0.$$

This definition is then usually "restated in a more efficient way". For example, in Keller's introductory paper:

> Let $(\bar{T}A,\Delta)$ denote the reduced tensor coalgebra on $A$, then an $A_\infty$-stuctures is a degree $1$ coderivation that squares to zero.

This re-definition is very mysterious to me. What was the original motivation? How would Stasheff(?) have come up with it?

Comment: This actually works for other operads. You can restate the homotopy condition by using a (co)derivation. I had the same doubt some years ago, however I recall I could understand more or less the motivation when I saw a paper regarding minimality of operads which was a condition for writing the operad by such (co)derivation. I will see if I can find this paper again and I will post it here.

Comment: I think this was the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411208 .

Comment: Yes, it works for the Lie operad too. If one thinks of the bracket as a map $\wedge^2 V\to V$ and extends it to the exterior coalgebra as a coderivation, then the Jacobi identity implies that the square is zero. It then becomes natural to consider an arbitrary coderivation that squares to $0$ to get what we call an $L_\infty$ structure.

Comment: This should be an instance of Koszul duality (at least that's what the cool people say). I don't know how to make it precise, and if anyone had a good reference I'd love to read it.

Comment: @DenisNardin Loday and Valette book have a chapter  on Koszul duality for quadratic algebras and a chapter on homotopy operadic algebras where the Koszul resolution is used.

Comment: Now I've found it. 10.1.17 in http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~loday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf states the condition explicitly for this correspondence using coderivations. More generally, 10.1.22 (Rosetta Stone) gives equivalent formulations for algebras up to homotopy.

Comment: So you're saying the point is that $\bar{T}A \simeq \mathcal{Ass}^¡ (A)$? The question remains then: How would anybody have known / come up with it (in the 60s)?

Comment: @jds I'm not sure if the associative version or if the Lie version came first. However motivating one of these versions is enough since the latter is the infinitesimal version of the former. In any case, in group cohomology and Lie algebra cohomology the equation $d^2 = 0$ plus the Leibniz rule is equivalent to a representation and this was known long time ago. Now upgrading to graded vector spaces, the condition $d^2 = 0$ turns into the up to homotopy version of these equations. So I think in the end the motivation comes from the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex.

Comment: @user40276 I agree that understanding the Lie case suffices. Can you elaborate on that? What kind of representation? Why would the representation know about homotopies?

Comment: Actually this works more generally for Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids (or even the infinity categorial case). For a vector bundle $A$ and a vector bundle $E$ there's the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex $CE^i (A , E) = \bigwedge^i A^* \otimes E$ a differential on this complex satisfying $d^2 = 0$ and the Leibniz rule is equivalent to a representation of $A$ on $E$. Picking $E$ the trivial vector bundle a representation is equivalent to the structure of a Lie algebroid on $A$, i.e., …..

Comment: ….  an anchor and a bracket and, for the case of a point, (i.e., vector space = vector bundle), a differential is equivalent to a bracket on $A$. Now we can upgrade $A$ and $E$ to a graded vector bundle and when $E$ is the trivial bundle this is equivalent to a structure of an Lie $\infty$-algebroid and, for the case of a point, a structure of a $L_{\infty}$-algebra. We can repeat an analogous process to Lie groupoids or groupoids which will give an $A_{\infty}$ structure instead of a $L_{\infty}$ one.